# Change a hidden input fields value when a radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the value of an hidden input field each time a user checks a radio button.

This is how my HTML looks like.

```
<input type="hidden" id="ZAAL_NAME" value="" name="ZAAL_NAME" />

<input type="radio" name="zaal_ID" value="ROOM1" onclick="change">
<input type="radio" name="zaal_ID" value="ROOM2" onclick="change"> 
<input type="radio" name="zaal_ID" value="ROOM3" onclick="change">
```

Now I want that each time I check a radio button, the value of that radio button becomes also the value of the hidden input field. Does anybody knows how to do that? Here is what I have so far.

```
   $('input[name="radbut"]').click(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    $('ZAAL_NAME').val(this.value);
});
```

Could anybody help ?

Kind regards,

Steaphann

Comment: Why would you want that? You'll end up with the same value in both `ZAAL_NAME` and `zaal_ID` when you submit the form. Why not just use `zaal_ID` in your server-side processing?

Comment: @lanzz I wish I could +1 your comment multiple times

Comment: Because I need to enter the ID in one table and the zaal_NAME in another one.  Also to give data to my database I must use the name attribute. That's why !

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your inline `onclick` handler won't work since you didn't include parentheses: it needs to be `onclick="change()"` to actually call your function. But you should change it to `onclick="change(this);"` to pass a reference to the clicked button to your function, then:

```
function change(el){
    $("#ZAAL_NAME").val(el.value) ;
}
```

Also you jQuery selector need a # to select by id.

Better though would be to remove the inline `onclick` from your markup and do it like this:

```
$('input[name="zaal_ID"]').click(function() {
    $('#ZAAL_NAME').val(this.value);
});
```

The latter would need to be in a document ready handler and/or in a script block that appears after your radio buttons in the page source.

Note: when getting the value of the clicked element you can say `$(el).val()` or `$(this).val()` (depending on which of the two functions you are looking at), but given that `el` and `this` are references to the DOM element you can just get its value property directly with `el.value` or `this.value`.

Comment: I've done it like your second way, but when I look into firebug it doesn't set the value

Comment: I've edited my post. But the console.log doesn't print anything

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice before that the # had been left off the beginning of the jQuery selector (needed to select by element id). Answer updated. Just saw your edit: where did "radbut" come from? That doesn't match the element name in your html...

Comment: Where should the # be placed ?

Comment: See my updated answer for the #. And my updated previous comment about "radbut".

Comment: radbut is the name of my radiobuttons

Comment: Can we maybe go in a little discussion, because it is still not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12031/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-nnnnnn)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[name="zaal_ID"]').change(function(){
   $('#ZAAL_NAME').val( this.value );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function change(){
   $("ZAAL_NAME").val( $(this).val() ) ;
}
```

or

```
function change(){
   $("ZAAL_NAME").val($("input[type='radio']:checked").val()) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try -

```
$(':radio').change(function(){
   $('#ZAAL_NAME').val($(this).val());
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KMXnR/

Answer (score 1):

use `onclick="change(this.value);"` and the function use like this

```
function change(e){
    $("ZAAL_NAME").val(e) ;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use is

```
$("input:radio[name=ZAAL_NAME]").click(function() {
     var value =  $(this).val(); 
     // or $('input:radio[name=theme]:checked').val(); 
     $("#ZAAL_NAME").val(value); 
 });
```

in short

```
$("input:radio[name=ZAAL_NAME]").click(function() {
     $("#ZAAL_NAME").val( $(this).val() ); 
 });
```