# Fill a hidden input with value Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new on js and I am struggling with this task can someone please give me a little help..
This is my code:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[1]" value="1" class="col"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[2]" value="2" class="col"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[3]" value="3" class="col"></td> 
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[4]" value="4" class="col"></td>
```

Here I got the hidden input that I need to fill with values that come from the js onchange event..

```
 <input type="hidden" name="row_col_nr[5]" value="0" class="row_nr">
```

And here I have my js code:

```
var row_col_nr = null;
$(".col").on("change", function () {
   row_col_nr = $( this ).val();
   alert(row_col_nr); // gives me the value of input that I select

});
```

My problem is that I do not know how take that `row_col_nr` values and put to the `hidden input` I do not know if I am telling right what is my problem.. If someone understands me can you please give me a little help..

Comment: what element is `minimal`

Comment: where did you apply `minimal` class?

Comment: sorry I eddited my code

Answer (score 1):

To set the value of the hidden input use the following code:

```
$(".row_nr").val(row_col_nr)
```

**Working demo below**

```js
var row_col_nr = null;
$(".col").on("change", function() {
  row_col_nr = $(this).val();
  alert(row_col_nr); // gives me the value of input that I select
  $(".row_nr").val(row_col_nr)
  console.log("the value of the hidden input is: " + $(".row_nr").val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[1]" value="1" class="col"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[2]" value="2" class="col"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[3]" value="3" class="col"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[4]" value="4" class="col"></td>

<input type="hidden" name="row_col_nr[5]" value="0" class="row_nr">
```

Comment: This works fine but when I submmit the  the row_col_nr gives me an array of only the last numbers like this 1=>4, 2=>4, 3=>4 .. maybe this is because   the inputs I have inside a for and the input looks like this:
@for($r = 1; $<=4; $r++)
<input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="1" class="col">
<input type="radio" name="col_nr[{{ $r  }}]" value="2" class="col">
... do I need to use .each or something so that value to come [1,2,3,4] not only the last selected.. hope you understand me thanks again .

Answer (score 1):

```
var row_col_nr = $('[name^="nr"]').val();
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Give an id, say hidden_input to the input which is hidden then use the following  code:

```
$(#hidden_input).val(row_col_nr );
```

If you don't want to add the id you can use the following:

```
$('input[value=row_col_nr][name="row_col_nr[5]"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    $('[name="retype-email"]').val($('[name="email"]').val());
    
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>Email:
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <br>
        <label>Hidden input: (visible for example purposes)</label><input name="retype-email">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is an example or you may visit [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849759/change-a-hidden-input-fields-value-when-a-radio-button-is-selected)

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

use `$('.row_nr').val(row_col_nr);` for store into `hidden input`

```js
var row_col_nr = null;
$(".col").on("change", function() {
  row_col_nr = $(this).val();
  alert(row_col_nr); // gives me the value of input that I select
  $('.row_nr').val(row_col_nr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[1]" value="1" class="col"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[2]" value="2" class="col"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[3]" value="3" class="col"></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="nr[4]" value="4" class="col"></td>
Here I got the hidden input that I need to fill with values that come from the js onchange event..

<input type="hidden" name="row_col_nr[5]" value="0" class="row_nr">
```