# Populate a field with another field value in gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I currently have a simple gravity form on my Wordpress website that includes a radio button field with 3 options: (Single, Married, Exempt).

I am wanting to dynamically populate a separate hidden text field on the same form with the value "Exempt" if the user selects the option Exempt in the radio button field. If the user selects one of the other options (Single or Married), I would like the value in the text field to be NULL.

Has anyone done something similar to this before, and if so, could you assist me with the steps to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change a hidden input fields value when a radio button is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849759/change-a-hidden-input-fields-value-when-a-radio-button-is-selected)

Comment: @APAD1 unfortunately this does not... That post is regarding if ANY radio button is selected then populate a hidden field, however, I am looking for when one specific radio button is selected then populate a hidden field. Thanks though!

Comment: It's the same concept, just target the radio button by it's `ID` instead of by `name`.

Comment: @APAD1 unfortunately I have no idea how to do that since I have no experience in javascript or any programming language really... Is there specific code you could assist me with that I could add to my functions.php file to accomplish that? The form ID is 25, the radio field ID is 9 (with option 3 "Exempt" being the target), and the hidden text field ID is 26. Thanks in advance for any assistance you are able to provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the code to a custom JavaScript file. You can read up on [enqueuing JavaScript files here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/). In your comment you only provide one ID for the `radio` inputs, but each input should have it's own unique ID. So assuming your only radio inputs on this form are those 3 inputs, you could also target by `type`(as I have done below). If you want to share the HTML of your form I can tailor the answer more to your specific scenario.

```js
// Document ready function for Wordpress
jQuery(function($) {
  $('form#25 input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    if (this.value === 'exempt') {
      $('input#26').val(this.value);
    } else {
      $('input#26').val(null);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
label {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="25">
  <label>Single<input type="radio" name="marriage-status" value="single" /></label>
  <label>Married<input type="radio" name="marriage-status" value="married" /></label>
  <label>Exempt<input type="radio" name="marriage-status" value="exempt" /></label>
  <!-- HIDDEN INPUT -->
  <input id="26" type="text" />
</form>
```

It looks like your form only has `radio` inputs for "Filing Status," so you can do it like this:

```js
// Document ready function for Wordpress
jQuery(function($) {
  $('form#gform_25 input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    if (this.value === 'Exempt') {
      $('input#input_25_24_valid').val(this.value);
    } else {
      $('input#input_25_24_valid').val(null);
    }
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding-left:0;
}
li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="gform_25">
  <li id="field_25_9" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
     <label class="gfield_label">Filing Status<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label>
     <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_radio">
        <ul class="gfield_radio" id="input_25_9">
           <li class="gchoice_25_9_0"><input name="input_9" type="radio" value="Single or Married filing sperately" id="choice_25_9_0"><label for="choice_25_9_0" id="label_25_9_0">Single or Married filing sperately</label></li>
           <li class="gchoice_25_9_1"><input name="input_9" type="radio" value="Married filing jointly" id="choice_25_9_1"><label for="choice_25_9_1" id="label_25_9_1">Married filing jointly (or Qualifying widow(er))</label></li>
           <li class="gchoice_25_9_2"><input name="input_9" type="radio" value="Head of household" id="choice_25_9_2"><label for="choice_25_9_2" id="label_25_9_2">Head of household (Check only if you're unmarried and pay more than half the costs of keeping up a home for yourself and a qualifying individual.)</label></li>
           <li class="gchoice_25_9_3"><input name="input_9" type="radio" value="Exempt" id="choice_25_9_3"><label for="choice_25_9_3" id="label_25_9_3">Exempt</label></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </li>
  
  <!-- Your hidden input -->
  <input type="text" class="gform_hidden" name="input_25_24_valid" id="input_25_24_valid">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the great information! I would love if you could assist with tailoring the code with the following HTML like you offered. You can find the HTML for the form at this URL x3tradesmen.com/staging-test. The radio button field is titled "Filing Status" with 4 options actually and has a field ID of 9, the hidden field I am trying to populate is titled "Exempt Hidden Field" and has a field ID of 37...Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It looks like the page is password protected, please update your question with the HTML that is being rendered for the form, that way if anyone comes across your question in the future, they will be able to see the code even if your website is no longer active or the code has changed.

Comment: I have removed the password protection on the page. Sorry about that.

Comment: My answer has been updated using the HTML that is being rendered for your form

Comment: Thank you for all your help!